# C program to chk validity of an expression

Tags: c

plz help me to find error in this program....
it is giving wrong ans...
if the expression is valid i m return 1 , else 0....
thanxx...

```
/* Check for balanced parentheses in an expression */
int chkexp(char exp[], int N)
{
  char arr[N];
  int top = 0, rslt, i;
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    { 
      if ((exp[i] == '(') || (exp[i]=='{') || (exp[i]=='['))
        {
          arr[top] = exp[i];
          top = top + 1;
        }
      else if ((exp[i] == ')') || (exp[i] == '}') || (exp[i] == ']'))
        { 
          if (arr[top] == exp[i])
            {
              --top;
              rslt = 1;
            }
          else
            {
              rslt = 0;
              break;
            } 
        }
    }
  if (top > 0)
    rslt = 0;
  return rslt;
}
```

Comment: What does "valid" mean?  Can you give the input, the actual output you got, and the expected output?  What have you tried for debugging?  Also, proper indentation wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 3):

`if(arr[top]==exp[i])` - well, that's not going to work, is it? E.g. '(' is not equal to ')'.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason you are failing is certainly copying a value in `arr[top]` then increase `top` then next time you try to compare to 'arr[top]' which is not initialized!!

Anyway even after you fix this, you will crash by what 500 -Internal Server Erro has said!  I suggest you to compare  the (ASCII) values, looking at the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) I noticed :

- `'(' = 40` and `')' = 41`
- `'[' = 91` and `']' = 93`
- `'{' = 123` and `'}' = 125`

So a condition like `if ( close - open >= 0 && close - open <= 2)` will satisfy.

The minor changes I made in your code are:

- initialize `rslt` to `0` and change it only in case of success.
- don't use a whole array only to store one `char` and compare to it.

```
int
chkexp(const char *const exp, const int N)
{
  /* char arr[N];  no need */
  char type;  /* to check type of expression () [] {} */
  int rslt = 0;  /* initialize result to false */
  int i;  /* loop index */
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
      if((exp[i] == '(') || (exp[i] == '{') || (exp[i] == '['))  /* when find opening */
        {
          type = exp[i];  /* type contains either '(' or '[' or '{' */
        }
      else if ((exp[i] == ')') || (exp[i] == '}') || (exp[i] == ']'))  /* when find closing */
        {
          if(exp[i] - type <= 2 && exp[i] - type >= 0)
            {
              rslt = 1;  /* the only case rslt flips to 1 */
            }
          break;
        }
    }

  return rslt;
}
```

Comment: Guys I couldn't indent the code more than that, if somebody can do it, would appreciate that ;)

Comment: I tried but - like you - I couldn't fix it. Perhaps there are some hidden garbage characters in there that throw off the SO editor - who knows.

Comment: I have edited your answer to fix the code display and took the liberty to make the program strictly conforming C90 and make consistent use of whitespace.  However, the program is wrong.  Apart from the obvious mistake that it always returns 0 (This looks like a copy & paste error since the assignment was indented in your original listing.) you are ignoring the fundamental finding of theoretical computer science that a palindrome language can only be recognized by a machine at least as powerful as a stack machine.  (Hence, the “no need” array is actually very needed.)